# CVSS v4 using lookup instead of simple formulas

Tags: risk-management, cvss

I wanted to know why in the CVSSv4 there is no longer an equation where you take the input of metrics and calculate the cvss output.
Rather they take the input metrics, use it to compute a vector (ex: `000010`), then look up for the cvss in the following table : [cvss_lookup.js](https://github.com/RedHatProductSecurity/cvss-v4-calculator/blob/main/cvss_lookup.js)

For instance for `000010` it is `9.8`. Am I misunderstanding how this works ? I feel like by doing this we are losing precision by doing a lookup instead of a simple formula to get the cvss ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details regarding the scoring system can be found in the [CVSS 4.0 specification](https://www.first.org/cvss/v4.0/specification-document). While the specification does not state *why* specific changes were done, it lists thar subject matter experts were consulted to group these vectors into more meaningful scores.

From personal experience, a lot of CVSS scores diverted greatly from my gut feeling. I've had vulnerabilities, that I would have placed somewhere between low-risk and informational, yet got a 7.3 in the CVSS vector. I'm certain a lot of people will agree that some CVSS scores are wildly inaccurate in regards to the actual risk presented by the vulnerability.

By forgoing the idea of a formula and essentially "handpicking" values, these new scores will hopefully be more accurate.